# Is it safe to call php service from onClick?

Tags: php

What I want know that is that when form data is POST to a php service directly from onClick="insert.php" then is it safe. Please explain your answer with details.
for example:

```
<form role="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>User Id</label>
                <input class="form-control" name="First Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>City Id</label>
                <input class="form-control" name="Last Name">
            </div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="allowStory.php">Allow</button><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="insert.php">Insert</button>
</form>
```

It also return to same page by executing php service as I wanted. But question is that is it safe? and is this type have any drawback? if yes then what are those?

Comment: It doesn't do anything. The `onclick` attribute has to contain Javascript code to execute.

Comment: If you open your console you'll see that you get an error every time you click on the button.

Comment: Yes, console does give errors. But data get inserted in database also.

Comment: That will be because your form is missing an `action`, so the form will be posting to the page it is already on. I'm assuming you probably have some code that inserts to your database in that same file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting a filename in `onclick` doesn't do anything, the `onclick` attribute has to contain Javascript code.

If you want a submit button to go to a specific script instead of the action of the form, use the `formaction` attribute.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" formaction="allowStory.php">Allow</button><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" formaction="insert.php">Insert</button>
```

It's perfectly safe to do this, it's no different from specifying the action of the form in the `action="scriptname.php"` attribute of the `<form>` tag.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question but rather a suggestion. You should leave this in the comments instead of answering. Not that it's a very good question to begin with.

Comment: @Shogunivar This answer is both an answer to the question, **and** a suggestion to what appears to be the OP's intention.

Comment: @Shogunivar I've added something about the safety of doing what he's obviously trying to do.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you sir, I was just concern about the safety and I also thank you for clearing my wrong methods.

Answer (score 0):

Use following HTML

```
             <form role="form" method="POST" id="formsend" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>User Id</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="First Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>City Id</label>
            <input class="form-control" name="Last Name">
        </div>
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></form>

            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
          <script>
          $(document).on('submit', '#formsend', function()
      {  
       $.post('savedate.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data)
        {

     $("#sent").html(data);   


        });

     return false;

     });
```

and create a savedata.php or any other name and put your php code to save data in it. you can not give filename to onclick event